# problem with NumberFormatted Factory in Java swings

Tags: java, swing

I use a jFormattedTextField for a telephone number and only to accept the numeric values i

declare it as "new NumberFormatterFactory(Integer.class, false)" .

Now the problem is when the number starts with 0(zero) like 001345.. , after entered the value and moved to next column the entered value is trimmed as 1345..  here it not accepting the 0 as the starting number.

how can I enter the number starts with 0

Comment: 001345 is the same 1345. If you are interested in the zero digits, you aren't looking for the number (Integer) but you are possibly looking for a string with numeric characters only.

Comment: If you declare it as Integer 0 wont be considered.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare it as `new NumberFormatterFactory(Integer.class, false)` which is for only `Integer`, `0` wont be considered. You need to change it to other formatter and not store Phone Number as number (i.e. Integer).

Check this example for phone number formatting:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JFormattedTextFieldaninputmaskforatelephonenumber.htm

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mer0625/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, telephone numbers are slightly different from integers in that sense.

Following [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/RegexFormatterwithaJFormattedTextField.htm) at you could solve it using regular expressions like this:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.regex.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter;

class RegexFormatter extends DefaultFormatter {
    private Pattern pattern;

    private Matcher matcher;

    public RegexFormatter() {
        super();
    }

    public RegexFormatter(String pattern) throws PatternSyntaxException {
        this();
        setPattern(Pattern.compile(pattern));
    }

    public RegexFormatter(Pattern pattern) {
        this();
        setPattern(pattern);
    }

    public void setPattern(Pattern pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public Pattern getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    protected void setMatcher(Matcher matcher) {
        this.matcher = matcher;
    }

    protected Matcher getMatcher() {
        return matcher;
    }

    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        Pattern pattern = getPattern();

        if (pattern != null) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

            if (matcher.matches()) {
                setMatcher(matcher);
                return super.stringToValue(text);
            }
            throw new ParseException("Pattern did not match", 0);
        }
        return text;
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JFormattedTextField formattedField =
                new JFormattedTextField(new RegexFormatter("\\d*"));
        frame.add(formattedField, "North");
        frame.add(new JTextField(), "South");
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```